# iphone application - update app using new project

Tags: iphone, xcode

Few weeks ago i built an iphone application and succesfully submitted it to the app store.
Now, the client wanted some features that i had made for another app, so i duplicated this second app(project)  in xcode and worked with it so it meets my client's needs.

My problem is that now i can't figure how i upload this project as an update for the first app.
I went to the application in itunesconnect and chose "Add Version", filled in the details (new version number and description), so now i have version 1.1 with status "Prepare for upload".

From xcode, i selected Product->archive, but in Archives Organizer, when i select Distribute->Submit to the IOS App Store, i get the following message: `No suitable application records were found. Please make sure you have set up a record for this application on iTunes Connect`
Does this mean that it does not recognise this app as the original uploaded in the app store?(maybe something to do with the app id?)

Am i missing something here? The Bundle Identifier for both projects is the same (as seen in Info.plist files).
Is this at all achievable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is what solved the issue:

I tried restarting xcode - but no luck.
Restarting my mac though solved it!

Answer (score 1):

It's defiantly achievable. Did you triple check that the bundle identifier is the same?

Try removing the version update in iTunes Connect and recreating it and redoing the process.

Best of luck!

-David